# Hypotheis testing R: problem with interpretation

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, contingency-tables

I'm doing an analysis about gender fair language in newspapers.
I have two variables that are important for my question.

First the variable "F_Rub_Wirtschaft" which asks if the column of the article is economy whereas "0 = Column is not economy" and "1 = Column is economy" and second the variable "Kat_Gen" which tells me how often gender fair language was used within an article and the levels of measurement are "0= No gender fair-language in article", 1= Mostly no gender-fair language in article", 2= Same amount of gendered and not gendered words in article", "3= Mostly gender-fair language in article" and "4= Only gender-fair language in article".

My data looks like this (but there is more rows than that):

| F_Rub_Wirtschaft | Kat_Gen |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |

My hypothesis is: If the Column of the Article is economy, there is less gender-fair language.

My problem is the following. In my actual dataset I have 20 Articles that have the column economy and 105 Articles have another column.

So when I do a CrossTable it obviously looks like there is less gender-fair language when the column is economy because there are not that many Articles that are of the column economy.

So how do I handle this? Does R automatically consider this when I'm running other tests like GoodmanAndKruskalGamma? How can I reliable test my hypothesis ?

Comment: R doesn't make any assumptions about your data. It just runs whatever functions you tell it to. It's just a calculator. It's up to you, the person analyzing the data, to know what to ask for. If you want advice about modeling data, then you should ask somewhere like [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic. This is not a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

So you classify the articles in two classes: about economy and about something else. Then you cross-classify with your other variable, that gives you a contingency table. Then you can test the hypothesis of independence between the factors with a chi-squared test.

Alternatively, you can use logistic regression.